# Generating a link within a controller with an HTTP verb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using a restful resource in Rails, I would like to be able to insert a link into my flash hash that the user can click to destroy the object in question. The only problem seems to be that I cannot get the generated link to work with the RESTful controller!

First I tried

```
link_to "Change your reservation", reservation_path(@existing_reservation), :method => :delete
```

This didn't work because link_to is a helper method in ActionView, not available in controllers

Next find was url_for

```
url_for :controller => 'reservations', :actions => 'destroy', :method => :delete
```

which took me back to the show action. I have tried every combination of the two that I can find . . . but I can't seem to create a link in my controller that will slip in the delete method! Every action I generate produces a normal link (GET), which calls the show method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplicationController.helpers.link_to` will allow you to use helper methods in the controllers, although I'm not sure that's strictly following MVC. Although occasionally I've found a need, i.e. calling `number_to_currency`.

Another problem arises when you use the :delete option in that particular helper. It will fail. After a quick glance at the source code I cant really see an immediate fix.

Firstly, I would recommend you put the delete link somewhere else on that page if possible. If you *really* need it in the flash you could modify the flash in the view.

I.e. in the controller setup the flash:

```
flash[:notice] = "Flash message with a  DELETE LINK in it"
```

Then in the view modify that flash before displaying it:

```
<%=  flash[:notice].gsub(/DELETE LINK/, link_to("delete", resource_path, :method => :delete)) %>
```

You would probably want to just make that into your own helper. If you don't like gsub-ing the text like that I'm sure you could find another way, how about just appending the link to the flash?

Hope that helps : )

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a path, try passing just the object itself, e.g.

```
link_to "Change your reservation", @existing_reservation, :method => :delete
```

Comment: Can't use the "link_to" method in controllers . . . its only for the views.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry, I didn't read your message closely enough. Short of hard-coding the link into the view, I'm pretty stumped on this one.